# Projecting 3D points to 2D plane

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, 2d, plane

Let A be a point for which I have the 3D coordinates x, y, z and I want to transform them into 2D coordinates: x, y. The projection shall be orthogonal on a plane defined by a given normal. The trivial case, where the normal is actually one of the axes, it's easy to solve, simply eliminating a coordinate, but how about the other cases, which are more likely to happen?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geometry (try http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Where is the 2D (0,0) point defined? Is the the point on the plane closest to the 3D origin? And how do you define which direction is the planar `x` and `y` axes?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you have your target point *P* with coordinates `r_P = (x,y,z)` and a plane with normal `n=(nx,ny,nz)` you need to define an origin on the plane, as well as two orthogonal directions for `x` and `y`. For example if your origin is at `r_O = (ox, oy, oz)` and your two coordinate axis in the plane are defined by `e_1 = (ex_1,ey_1,ez_1)`, `e_2 = (ex_2,ey_2,ez_2)` then orthogonality has that `Dot(n,e_1)=0`,  `Dot(n,e_2)=0`, `Dot(e_1,e_2)=0` (vector dot product). Note that all the direction vectors *should* be normalized (magnitude should be one).

Your target point *P* must obey the equation:

```
r_P = r_O + t_1*e_1 + t_2*e_2 + s*n
```

where `t_1` and `t_2` are your 2D coordinates along `e_1` and `e_2` and `s` the normal separation (distance) between the plane and the point.

There scalars are found by projections:

```
s = Dot(n, r_P-r_O)
t_1 = Dot(e_1, r_P-r_O)    
t_2 = Dot(e_2, r_P-r_O)
```

Example with a plane origin `r_O = (-1,3,1)` and normal:

```
n = r_O/|r_O| = (-1/√11, 3/√11, 1/√11)
```

You have to pick orthogonal directions for the 2D coordinates, for example:

```
e_1 = (1/√2, 0 ,1/√2)
e_2 = (-3/√22, -2/√22, 3/√22)
```

such that `Dot(n,e_1) = 0` and `Dot(n,e_2) = 0` and `Dot(e_1, e_2) = 0`.

The 2D coordinates of a point *P* `r_P=(1,7,-3)` are:

```
t_1 = Dot(e_1, r_P-r_O) = ( 1/√2,0,1/√2)·( (1,7,-3)-(-1,3,1) ) =  -√2
t_2 = Dot(e_2, r_P-r_O) = (-3/√22, -2/√22, 3/√22)·( (1,7,-3)-(-1,3,1) ) = -26/√22
```

and the out of plane separation:

```
s = Dot(n, r_P-r_O) = 6/√11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think your answer is better than the first. I was thinking of something like that myself but you clarified things for me. One more question: How do I compute e_1 and e_2?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10703674/380384

Comment: Alternatively you can define your directions based of radial and tangential vectors from the 3D origin (projected onto the plane), or by the intersection of the plane with the `XY` or `YZ` or `ZX` planes.

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to define orthogonal vectors to the normal vector. This should be decided when the plane is defined, and not when the point is measured.

Comment: Shouldn't these vectors be _orthonormal_ rather than orthogonal?

Comment: Hmm, I never mentioned `e_1` and `e_n` should be normalized. My bad.

Answer (score 10):

[Find the projection of `A` onto the normal direction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection). Then subtract that projection from `A`. What is left is the projection of `A` onto the orthogonal plane.

The projection of A onto the unit normal direction `n` is given by:

```
(A · n) n
```

If `A = (x, y, z)` and the unit normal is given by `n = (nx, ny, nz)`, then the projection of A onto `n` is

```
(x*nx + y*ny + z*nz) n
```

So the projection of A onto the orthogonal plane is

```
A - (A · n) n
= (x, y, z) - (x*nx + y*ny + z*nz) (nx, ny, nz)
```

---

For example, if A = (1,2,3) and n is the unit normal in direction (4,5,6), then

```
In [12]: A
Out[12]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [17]: d
Out[17]: array([4, 5, 6])

In [20]: n = d/sqrt(4*4 + 5*5 + 6*6)   # make n a unit vector
In [13]: n
Out[13]: array([ 0.45584231,  0.56980288,  0.68376346])
```

So the projection of A onto the orthogonal plane is

```
In [15]: A - np.dot(A,n)*n
Out[15]: array([-0.66233766, -0.07792208,  0.50649351])
```

---

How to find 2D coordinates:

You'll need to define a 2D coordinate system on the orthogonal plane. In other words, you need to define where the `x-axis` and `y-axis` are. For example, you could define the `x-axis` to be the projection of (1,0,0) onto the orthogonal plane (using the computation shown above). This will work except in the degenerate case where (1,0,0) is normal to the plane.

Once you have unit vectors for the `x` and `y` axis directions, then you could project `A` directly onto `x` and `y`. The magnitude of those vectors are the 2D coordinates.

For example, this is the projection of (1,0,0) onto the plane. We take this to be the x-axis direction:

```
In [42]: x = np.array([1,0,0])    
In [45]: x = x - np.dot(x, n) * n
In [52]: x /= sqrt((x**2).sum())   # make x a unit vector    
In [53]: x
Out[53]: array([ 0.89006056, -0.29182313, -0.35018776])
```

Here we compute the y-axis direction: The `y-axis` direction must be perpendicular to both the normal direction `n` and to `x`. So we could define `y` to be the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of `n` and `x`:

```
In [68]: y = np.cross(n, x)

In [69]: y
Out[69]: array([ -2.77555756e-17,   7.68221280e-01,  -6.40184400e-01])
```

So here are the coordinates for `A` in the plane:

```
In [70]: np.dot(A, x), np.dot(A, y)
Out[70]: (-0.74414898890755965, -0.38411063979868798)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do I transform them into 2D coordinates now? I mean removing the z coordinate, like projecting it to a screen.

Comment: I think you are over complicating things. All you need is dot products to get the projection distances (coordinates).