# Mapping a Coplanar Set of 3D points to Their Planar 2D Coordinates

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, vector-graphics, triangulation

I have a set of 3D points of a mesh and normals at each point. Points lie on the same plane which are obtained from cutting a 3d model along an arbitrary plane.

The problem is - I need to map these 3D points to their planar 2d coordinates (u,v), that can be used to form Delaunay triangulation of the mesh. So I need a transformation matrix that transforms these 3d coplanar points to their planar 2D coordinates.

Comment: I don't know why you need a matrix since in your case it's a simple projection. If you're using C++, the CGAL library has an example of how to do a 2D triangulation how of 3D coplanar points [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title14).

Comment: Actually I am using "Triangle" library for triangulation, that needs 2D coordinates. Thats why I need to transform the points to local 2D points.

Comment: Then just use u=y and v=z

Comment: If I have a set of 3D points obtained after cutting a 3D model along some arbitrary plane, then what would be the transformation ? As this time we have different coordinates for all the points, we just cannot ignore any of the (x,y,z) coordinate.

Comment: Update your question then. Your are writing "a plane perpendicular to x-axis"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Projecting 3D points to 2D plane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472048/projecting-3d-points-to-2d-plane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to define a plane perpendicular at all points to your normal vectors. In that case, you simply let the `Z` component of each vector to the point on your surface equal `0` giving you a two-dimensional representation of your surface on the defined plane. Your transformation (or properly `rotation`) matrix is then defined with respect to the plane.

The details of the approach are given at [**plane (Geometry)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29) and the nuts and bolts of how to do it are shown at [**Defining a plane in R3 with a point and normal vector**](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/dot_cross_products/v/defining-a-plane-in-r3-with-a-point-and-normal-vector).