# Convert 3D coordinate to 2D coordinate using axonometric and isometric projection

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, projection, isometric

I'm currently working on a game in JS using HTML5 canvas and I need to convert a 3D coordinate defined by`x`, `y`, `z` to 2D coordinate defined by `x'` and `y'` using two projections mode : axonometric first and then isometric.

I have already read the wiki page of isometric projection to find formula but I don't understand that :

Wikipedia formula:

[image]

Why it's using matrix rotation and where is the `x'` and `y'` 2D result ?

Can someone give me the formulas to convert a point of 3D axes in 2D axes using axonometric projection and the formula using isometric projection with explanation for beginner in mathematical?

Comment: Because isometric projection is basically a rotation, followed by a dimension-reduction (i.e. just throw the z-coordinate of the result away).

Comment: @NicoSchertler So the formula is `x' =(x−z) * cos(30)` and `y' = y+(x+z)⋅sin(30)` ?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection#Mathematics), it is `x'=(x-z)/sqrt(2)` and `y'=(x+2y+z)/sqrt(6)`, which looks similar to your equation except for a scaling factor of `1/2`.

Comment: Thank's and how I can apply this formula for axonometric projection with any angle ?

Comment: Just use the rotation-based formula and plug in your angles.

Comment: Right, thank's i'm going to try it

Answer (score 2):

3D to 2D isometric:

```
x'=(x-z)/sqrt(2)
y'=(x+2y+z)/sqrt(6)
```

(Based on @NicoSchertler's comment. He says he got it from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) but I don't see how..)

For other axonometric see also: [Projecting 3D points to 2D plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472048/projecting-3d-points-to-2d-plane)

Answer (score 0):

```
x'=(x-z)/sqrt(2)
y'=(x+2y+z)/sqrt(6)
```

if x, y = 0 and z = 100 I get the resulting coordinate (-70, 40)..

Thus I don't think this formula is correct.. I'd post this as a comment, but the rules on this site make zero sense and don't let me.