# Python - 3D point to 2D coordinate

Tags: python, geometry, projection, 3d-engine

I'm working on a 3D engine using only the standard python libraries.
I'm using Tkinter to display points.
I'd like to convert a given 3D (x, y, z) point to a 2D (x, y) coordinate to be displayed on a screen by drawing a line from one to the other.
I have tried searching online for how to do this but the answers don't seem to cover for all of my inputs.
I'd like to get a function that uses

- Camera X
- Camera Y
- Camera Z
- Camera Rotation X
- Camera Rotation Y
- Point X
- Point Y
- Point Z

to produce my 2D coordinate.
I don't really have any code to show since nothing I tried got close to doing what I want.
Thanks

Comment: This essentially is a general math/geometry question, and not really about programming, since the same technique for projecting 3d points on to a 2d plane would be used regardless of the language. There are a lot of articles and tutorials on the subject, so can you explain why none of those helped and why you're asking here? There are questions on this site like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23472048/6273251) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/724219/6273251) which ask essentially the same thing.

Comment: Wikipedia [3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). It shows `Mathematical formula` to convert 3D to 2D. `a` is 3D point, `c` is camera, `b` in `2D`

Comment: You said "from one to the other".  What is the "other"?